# Can we detect orbiting light?

Tags: black-holes, singularities

Suppose our universe is located inside a black hole. How can we differentiate between light that comes directly from an object to light that made several orbits around the singularity before reaching us?

Comment: Isn't this just gravitational lensing? Is it even possible to make more than one full orbit and then get flung out?

Comment: The big bang singularity and the black hole singularities are not the same thing .https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/universe.html

Comment: @safesphere Would light orbit the singularity inside a white hole?